# Accessing json array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have created json array like this,

```
data = [{ product_id: 1, manufacturer: 'man1', product: 'test1' },
        { product_id: 2, manufacturer: 'man2', product: 'test2' }]
```

I want to list this data in tabular format without using key name. 
I have tried like,

```
for(i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    console.log(data[i].product_id+","+data[i].product+","+data[i].manufacturer);
}
```

Its working fine. But I want to display values without specifying key name like, `.product_id`,`.product` etc..Is it possible in javascript? Could you please support me to resolve this?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What do you mean you want to do it without specifying a key name? That's the typical way of getting the value. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an iterator of all the values of the object. For example to log them all to the console separated by commas without specifying each key you could:

```js
let data = [
  { product_id: 1, manufacturer: 'man1', product: 'test1' },
  { product_id: 2, manufacturer: 'man2', product: 'test2' }
]

for(i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    console.log(Object.values(data[i]).join(','))
}
```

This will list the objects *own property* names, so it won't follow the prototype chain up (if that matters).

*EDIT based on comment (using `padEnd()` to specify a fixed width):*

```js
let data = [
    { product_id: 1, manufacturer: 'man1', product: 'test1' },
    { product_id: 2, manufacturer: 'man2', product: 'test2' }
  ]

let fixedWidth = 7
for(i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    let padded = Object.values(data[i])
    .map(str => String(str).padEnd(fixedWidth, " "))
    .join('')
    console.log(padded)
 }
```

Comment: can we specify width between each values?

Comment: @RugmaManas, I'm not sure what you are trying to do. It's a little unusual to specify layout when writing to the console, but you could `map` each value to a string and use `string.padStart` or `padEnd` (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for in` statement to iterate over an object, like this:

```
data = [{ product_id: 1, manufacturer: 'man1', product: 'test1' },
        { product_id: 2, manufacturer: 'man2', product: 'test2' }]
for(object of data){
  for(key in object){
    console.log(object[key])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```js
var data = [{ product_id: 1, manufacturer: 'man1', product: 'test1' }, { product_id: 2, manufacturer: 'man2', product: 'test2' } ]

const log = (padLength) => data.forEach(x => console.log(Object.values(x).join(' '.repeat(padLength))))

log(2)
log(5)
```

Using `forEach` since data is already an array as well as `Object.values` to get the values in an array followed by a `join` which uses the padLength parameter to repeat the number of empty spaces.

Comment: Issue fixed. Tnx :)